# How to edit fstab when stuck in emergency mode?

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, vim

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on a vmware and I've been struggling solving the the "you are in the emergency mode" problem.
By mistake I commented out the first line (the one with the errors=remount at the end of the line) in fstab:
[contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we5FT.jpg)

and now I cant do nothing even in the recovery mode where I used vim to edit fstab and got this when tried to INSERT:

[swapfile problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp8U6.jpg)

and then this:

[writing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYbsT.jpg)

I really don't know how to solve the problem and would appreciate any help. It seems that either of problems above is a seperate topic but I thought they are related to my original problem (the emergency mode).

[mount output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLYnF.jpg)

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I think at this point the whole file system is mounted read-only. You need to unmount it and mount it with the `-o rw` option. Then you will be able to modify (as root) files like `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: if you need to do it from a live USB/CD then [this reference](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=233470) may help.

Comment: @Jos Thanks. I just tried that but that didn't change anything

Comment: Must be some other kind of permissions problem then. Please add the output of the `mount` command, and of `ls -l /etc/fstab` to your question.

Comment: @Jos I added a screenshot of the commands, thanks.

Comment: You mounted `/dev/sda6` under `/media/untitled/`, which is fine, but then the file to be edited is of course `/media/untitled/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @Jos The command I used didn't create that directory (../untitled/etc/fstab), so nothing found.

Comment: Then what did it create? I see no error message, and according to your fstab, `/dev/sda6` contains your file system root. That doesn't add up.

Comment: @Jos Yes there was no error. but when I %ls in /media it only shows "username" directory and there no sign of untitled/...

Comment: You need to create the mount point first. Also, what's there in the syslog after you try the mount command?

Comment: @Jos thanks, I cant make any directory, its a readonly file system. I think I have to do it with the live CD.